# Can't use createRef in latest version of create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I am learning React using **create-react-app**, and I'm getting this error in my app:

```
TypeError: react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default.a.createRef() is not a function
```

Now, I know that this feature was only introduced in React 16.3, but that seems to be the version I have installed. I initialized everything by typing:

```
npx create-react-app probando02
```

If I check my version:

```
npm view react version
16.13.1
```

And my package.json file is:

```
{
  "name": "probando02",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

EDIT: my React environment, as shown by `npx create-react-app --info`:

```
Environment Info:

  current version of create-react-app: 3.4.1
  running from C:\Users\paulo\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_npx\21716\node_modules\create-react-app

  System:
    OS: Windows 10 10.0.18362
    CPU: (24) x64 AMD Ryzen Threadripper 1920X 12-Core Processor
  Binaries:
    Node: 12.16.3 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.EXE
    Yarn: Not Found
    npm: 6.14.7 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.CMD
  Browsers:
    Edge: 44.18362.449.0
    Internet Explorer: 11.0.18362.1
  npmPackages:
    react: ^16.13.1 => 16.13.1
    react-dom: ^16.13.1 => 16.13.1
    react-scripts: 3.4.1 => 3.4.1
  npmGlobalPackages:
    create-react-app: Not Found
```

So what's going on?

Answer (score 1):

I am using the same version but it works fine for me.

[image]
And also here is my package.json file

```
{
  "name": "example",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

It worked fine for me it was launching the default website in port 3000.
I think its just a update issue or so, just try updating npm.

Comment: Nope. Just tried updating both npm and reinstalling (deleting node_modules and going 'npm install' again). The same error happens